# electron how to create delta file

Tags: electron

I use `electron-builder` to build my app and succeed to build the first version which contains three outputs: foosetup.exe, foo-0.0.1-full.nupkg and RELEASES.Now I want to implement the auto-update and I have deployed a back-end service by using `electron-release-server`.

The auto-update need to set a `feedURL` which will be used to fetch updates,but the problem is that I don't know what the updates exactly means?Is it the `foo-0.0.1-full.nupkg` or the `foo-0.0.1-delta.nupkg` or another file?

The second problem is that I don't know how to create the delta file.I can just find an option `remoteReleases` in `electron-builder` which is `a URL to your existing updates.If given,these will be downloaded to create delta file`.But what's the URL exactly means?I find a example i which `"remoteRelease": "https://github.com/user/repo"`，and it creates some releases and uploads many extra files for each release such as `foosetup.exe`, `foo-xx-full-nupkg`, `RELEASES`.I guess `electron-builder` will fetch the `${remoteReleases/release/download/some-version/xxx}` to download file and then diff the two file to create delta file,but I can't upload `RELEASES` when I create release on github,it reports that `they don't support this file type`.
Is there anyone can help?There're to few docs to follow for a beginer

Comment: I'm pretty much in the same boat here. There seems to be no doc on where `remoteReleases` should point to. The root? On `releases`? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **electron-release-server** please take a look at [the docs](https://github.com/ArekSredzki/electron-release-server/blob/master/docs/update-windows.md).

The delta-file will be create automatically if you use *electron-builder*. But in order for this to work `remoteReleases` must be set to a valid (and reachable) URL **plus** there must at least an empty file called `RELEASES`. So for the very first build just create an empty file and call it `RELEASES`.

On every future build there will be a `RELEASES` file created for you. Throw all the generated files in your release server (overwrite existing `RELEASES`) and it'll be fine.

**Attention:** For `electron-release-server` you do not need the `RELEASES` generated by `electron-builder`. `electron-release-server` will create one by itself.

---

To get started with auto-updates I'd recommend that you set up a dead-simple release-server locally. I.e.:

- Create a directory and throw an empty file `RELEASES` in there.
- Then start a simple webserver pointing at that directory (e. g. `cd into/your/dir && php -S 0.0.0.0:80`).
- Edit your `package.json`: `"remoteRelease": "http://localhost"`
- Then build your installer: `npm run dist`
  It should successfully build and you should see some GET requests on your local server.
- Take the generated files and stuff them into the directory you created.
- Now increment your version and start another build: `npm run dist`
  You should see some GET requests again and there should be an addition delta-file being created.
- Again stuff all those things into the directory (or for electron-release-server upload the assets .nupkg, .exe and delta into a new release).

Hope that helps. Feel free to comment if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample app that I have created https://github.com/electron-delta/electron-sample-app

It uses two npm packages.

1. @electron-delta/builder
2. @electron-delta/updater

More details https://github.com/electron-delta/electron-delta#installation