# electron - incremental updating?

Tags: linux, electron, electron-packager

I am using [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) & [electron-packager](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue).
I am wondering whether I can do something like *incremental updating*, that is, after running an electron *build* command, I don't need to copy the whole `electron-linux-x64` folder to my dist machine to update it to the newest, but instead I only need to copy some files in the folder.

Here is what I found up to now: I edit some code for the `renderer` process. Then I let `electron-packager` to build a package for `linux`. Then I find that not all the generated files have been changed. Instead, it seems that only the `resources/*.asar` have been changed. If I just copy these files to the dist machine, it seems that the machine updates well. But I am not sure whether some hidden files are changed too.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are some upvotes to this question, and after three years I have gained more knowledge let me answer myself, making whoever reads this post can find a solution :)

Firstly, in 2020 there may already have solutions. For instance, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802245/electron-how-to-create-delta-file) and [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/updates).

Secondly, you can also use `rsync` to *only* copy the *changed* parts in a folder. Moreover, if a big file (say 10GB) only changes a little bit in the middle (say 1MB), it will *only transfer* that little bit (say 1MB). This is a general tool and can be used everywhere.

Lastly, as a side remark, *manually* copy your file to the development server is *not* a good idea. Try to automate this process. The simplest would be a several-line bash script using `scp`/`rsync` and so on, and the most complex may be Kubernetes and Docker.